# Need to run a query on a Transactions table with multiple entries for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has columns for id, user_id, payer_id, amount, status, date etc.
Multiple users have multiple transactions...

I need to query 1 (RANDOM) transaction per user, for ALL users.

So if there are 100 users, and 10000 transactions, the result must give me 100 transactions in total as there are 100 users, irrespective of how many transactions each user has.

I have read that DISTINCT and GROUP BY must be used but I have not found a way for this to work.

The problem may be with the random part, any advise?

Comment: select * from table group by user_id;

Comment: The query works for retrieving one entry per user, but it does not take a random entry...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from (select * from table order by rand())as random group by random.user_id;
```